# Need caption in Photo Pop up using Facebook Album Graph API

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fancybox

I came across a custom Jquery (fBAlbum.js) by a Zach about embedding facebook Pages Photo's on a website 
Thing is it gives out exactly what i need with a few tweaks 
But i am not able to get the Caption of the Photo which is on facebook on the website as it pops out on the website using Fancy Box. 
Is there a possible way to work out this
I have uploaded a Fiddle Link & the JQuery script for reference.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MY_DIV_ID').fbAlbum({
            'albumID': 531734903621391,
            'callback': function () {   //code that loads after the album must go here
                $(".album a").fancybox();
            }
        });
    });
```

**[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/S3pH9/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your script is returning each `<img>` tag with a `title` attribute like :

```
<img title="Sample" src="https://simage.jpg?oh=123&amp;oe=456" />
```

What you could do is to add a `titleFormat` callback to fancybox (v1.3.4) to get the value of that attribute and set it as its caption like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MY_DIV_ID').fbAlbum({
        albumID: 531734903621391,
        callback: function () { //code that loads after the album must go here
            $(".album a").fancybox({
                titlePosition: 'inside',
                titleFormat: function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return "<div>" + $("#MY_DIV_ID").find("img").eq(currentIndex).attr("title") + "</div>";
                }
            }); // fancybox
        }
    }); // fbAlbum
}); // ready
```

See your forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/syHQ5/)**